# Difference between two String constructors

Tags: java, string, constructor

I'm wondering the difference between the following 2 statements:

```
    String str = new String(new char[]{'a', 'b'});
```

and

```
    String str = new String(new byte[]{'a', 'b'});
```

I get the same thing in the outcome. The only difference i can think of is that 
i don't have to convert the array type to `byte[]` when i have a `char[]` and vice versa.

TIA.

Comment: The encoding mechanism required for each...From the [JavaDocs for `String(byte[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(byte[])) *"Constructs a new String by decoding the specified array of bytes using the platform's default charset"*, the `char[]` array is already encoded...

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that the first is just taking a character array and creating a string of the same length, with the same `char` contents. The second is *decoding* from bytes to chars - using the platform default encoding in this case. You can specify the encoding with another constructor argument, and indeed you should almost always do so. (It's very rarely a good idea to use the platform default encoding - and when you want to do so, it's clearer if you do so explicitly.)

For the values of `'a'` and `'b'` it's *unlikely* that there'll be a difference in results - although the platform default encoding *could* be EBCDIC or something else similarly non-ASCII-compatible. But it's worth understanding that fundamentally these are two different operations.

It's a *little* bit like constructing an image, where the first form would be passing in an array of a mythical `PixelColor` type, whereas the second form would be more like saying "load it from this PNG file".